# How to use Python format function in this case

Tags: python

I need to send a request through a link. The following link works and could return what I need:

```
response = requests.get(
    """https://pangeare.freshservice.com/api/v2/assets?include=type_fields&filter="updated_at:>%272022-10-09%27"&page="""+ str(page),
    auth = ('xxxxxxxxx', ''),
    headers = headers
)
```

You could see that the `updated_at` filter is hard coded into the url. If I try to use format function to fill the updated_at value, it will return 400

```
response = requests.get(
   """https://pangeare.freshservice.com/api/v2/assets?include=type_fields&filter="updated_at:>{0}"&page=""".format('2022-10-09') + str(page),
    auth = ('xxxxxxxxxxxx', ''),
    headers = headers
)
```

What is the appropriate way to use format function in this case?

Comment: You're missing a `%27` from both sides of the date...

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way to do this whole operation would be to use the [`params` option](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=params#passing-parameters-in-urls)

You can also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) instead of `.format()`.

```
BASE_URL_PATH = "https://pangeare.freshservice.com/api/v2/assets"

date_str = "2022-10-09"

response = requests.get(
    BASE_URL_PATH,
    params={
        "include": "type_fields",
        "filter": f"\"updated_at:>%27{date_str}%27\"",
        "page": page,
    }
    auth = ('xxxxxxxxxxxx', ''),
    headers = headers
)
```

Comment: Why you use this format f"\"updated_at:>%27{date_str}%27\"", instead of updated_at:>%27{date_str}%27"?

Comment: In your post, the filter query has quotes in it, so they still need to be included in the string. `filter="updated_at:>{0}"` Presumably this is why you wrapped with `"""` in the first place.